# Find rows having min and max range values that covers the selected millions of values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with symbol names (e.g. functions) and their start memory address and end memory address placement. Now I want to look up many addresses that are between the start and end addresses and map to each symbol name (or simpler the start addr as below example).

I do a query like this:

```
SELECT r.caller_addr AS caller_addr,sm.addrstart AS caller FROM rets AS r 
JOIN symbolmap AS sm ON r.caller_addr BETWEEN sm.addrstart AND sm.addrend;
```

rets is a table that contains approximately a million caller_addr. The symbolmap table is created as:

```
CREATE TABLE 
  symbolmap  
  (addrstart BIGINT NOT NULL, 
   addrend BIGINT NOT NULL, 
   name VARCHAR(45), 
   PRIMARY KEY (addrstart), 
   UNIQUE INDEX (addrend)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

All the addrstart to addrend rows are none overlapping, i.e. there can only be one row hit for any requested addr (r.caller_addr in the example). The symbolmap table contains 42000 rows. I have tried a few other index methods as well, but still the select takes very long time (many 10s of minutes) and has not managed to finish.

Any suggestions on better indexes or other select statements that have better performance? I'm running this on MySQL 5.1.41 and I don't need to worry about portability.

When I have searched for what others do I only find results with constant boundaries and not when finding the row having the right boundaries. But it seems to me like a quite general problem.

Comment: You missed the condition that specifies relation between your `r` and `sm` tables.

Comment: is not `r.caller_addr BETWEEN sm.addrstart AND sm.addrend` specifying the relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to combine the two columns in a single index:

```
CREATE TABLE 
  symbolmap  
  (addrstart BIGINT NOT NULL, 
   addrend BIGINT NOT NULL, 
   name VARCHAR(45), 
   PRIMARY KEY (addrstart, addrend)
  ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Also make sure that caller_addr is also bigint

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I have not timed it but it seems to improve with the combined index. I decided to solve the main issue of the millions of rows with addresses by creating a temporary table with the distinct ones which was only a couple of thousands. Then I create another temporary table from the above select query. This last table can now be used to do a simple equality join directly from any of the millions of rows to the symbol. This was much quicker, in total only 30 seconds or so on my machine.